# Access Azure Virtual Machine by IP Address

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have setup a Virtual Machine on Windows Azure and deployed my application that listens to a port; Can I access my application with IP Address of that Machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access your application via the IP provided. You have to ensure that, the required port ( Say 80 ) is opened i.e. in the terminologies of Azure - Open End Point.

I have assumed that you would have deployed a web application that can accessed via a browser using HTTP or HTTPS.

For More Info - [How to Set Up Endpoints to a Virtual Machine](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/)

Comment: Thanks, i already create endpoint, but i made a mistake because my protocol uses UDP protocol, but i accidentally created TCP protocol, but,yes this is correct answer.